# How to remove every other element from a list only using List.hd, List.tl, and List.length

Tags: ocaml

Write a function that removes every other element from a list. `['d'; 'o'; 'u'; 'c'; 'h'; 'e'; 'c'; 'a'; 'n'; 'o'; 'e'] -> ['d'; 'u'; 'h'; 'c'; 'n'; 'e']`

It has to be a recursive method, and you can ONLY use `List.hd`, `List.tl`, and `List.length`, all the others are no bueno.

Here's an example of a function to remove the last element of a list: it should apparently be done similarly:

```
let rec rm_last_element l = 
    if  List.tl  l = [] 
      then []  
    else List.hd l :: remove_last(List.tl l);;
```

Comment: Have you tried doing anything at all? Are you not able to solve even part of the problem? Like dropping a single element from the list? Or printing every other element?

Comment: I've tried. Apparently the solution is super easy, but I just can't see it. It also doesn't help that this is the last ocaml problem that I have to do, and then I can move on and forget this language even exists.
I was thinking of writing a function that removes the first element, and remove it depending on if the length of the list is odd or even? But I can't do even that

Comment: I'm not sure that despising the language to ask for some help is the way to go ;-) Try to show some work from you, even in pseudo-code, and we'll help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider what a list in OCaml looks like:

`[1 ; 4; 6; 3; 8; 9; 10]` can be written as `1 :: 4 :: 6 :: 3 :: 8 :: 9 :: 10 :: []`.

We can pattern match against a list. (Expanding on what Butanium showed.)

```
match [1 ; 4; 6; 3; 8; 9; 10] with
(* The case of an empty list *)    
| [] -> 
(* The case of a list with a single element,
   where the single element has the value 1. *)
| elt :: [] -> 
(* The case of a list with at least two elements, 
   where elt1 is 1, and elt2 is 4 and 
   rest is [6; 3; 8; 9; 10] *)
| elt1 :: elt2 :: rest ->
```

If you want to drop every other element, what would each case need to return?  What would we get if we did the same match on `[6; 3; 8; 9; 10]`? What would `elt1`, `elt2`, and `rest` be in that case?

Comment: Thank you so much Chris, with your explanation, it was very straightforward. One question, do you know if it's possible to do conditional statements when pattern matching? Say I'm working on a list that contains lists of integers:

| list is empty -> do this
| if the first list (head) has an even number of integers -> do this
| if not -> do this

Do you know if that's possible? I'm getting syntax errors and I can't find any examples of that online. Thanks again, you were very helpful

Comment: You're very welcome. I think what you're looking for are conditional guards on patterns. There is a section on these on this page. [link](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/data_types_and_matching.html). In the case you mention: `match lst with [] -> ... | lst when List.length lst mod 2 = 0 -> ... | lst -> ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do use a pattern matching like this :

```ml
match l with
| x1 :: x2 :: tail -> (* remove x2 :  x1 is the first element x2 the second
   and tail is the rest of the list *) 
| _ -> (* else don't change the list*)
```

For more info about pattern matching (which is implicitly the same as `List.hd` and `List.tail` see [this link](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/data_types_and_matching.html)